# Can't move point light or any light in blender

Tags: interface

[image: it always just makes this box]So this has never happened before but recently in blender when i try to move the point light it doesn't move and just creates a box, i was following a tutorial and you HAVE to use point light to make it look good, and it just won't move. And all the lights don't move either, its in blender 5.3.1, anyone know how to fix this? I searched everywhere and no one else has the same problem.

Comment: In the panel called Object Types Visibility (on the top), is Light enabled for selectability

Comment: share some screenshots or gifs

Comment: @Karan i added the picture

Comment: @moonboots i think i went to it is it on the top right corner where it shows restrictions?

Comment: @moonboots but i found in orientation if i change it from box it goes to a circle. does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: @moonboots also when i use it on another item like a block it highlights the like x, y, and z when i hover over it but that doesn't happen when i use the light, and i tried all the other lights and i think its only the lights for some reason i don't know.

Comment: @moonboots oh and i found a solution where i have to hit g to move it but i cant use arrows still, if u find a reason fro problem please tell me so i can still use arrows

Comment: does it happen in a particular blend file or is it the same with any new file?

Comment: which blender version are you using?

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like you have the correct active tool and drag mode.  You are in object mode as you should. The light object is actually selected as we can see it highlighted in the viewport and outliner, that also tells us it's not a selection constraint either. None of the gizmo's channel are invisible, so we know you don't have any of the location channels locked. We don't see constraint on that light object from the outliner.

Comment: Maybe try to upload your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the link here so that we can check ourselves. But quite frankly, I can't think of any other possible culprit from there. So if I were you, I would go to the menu Help > Report a bug, and follow the procedure there.

Comment: @Karan im using blender 3.5.1

Comment: @moonboots its the same with any file

Comment: @L0Lock idk how to use it so do u have discord? if so add me and send me a message mine is zealyplayz

Comment: You literally just have to follow the instructions. Drag your file in the dotted box, check the boxes, put your question's link in the text field and hit upload. In the next page, under the "**Share this file**" title, there will be a bunch of text to copy into your question.

Comment: use blender `3.5.1 Stable` or `3.6.0 LTS`

Comment: @Karan is right actually, first try using the latest stable Blender version (which is 3.6.0 LTS right now), just in case it's a bug that got fixed. **Refuse when asked if you want to import your settings from last version**, in case it's an issue with your settings. Then if not better, please share a file.

Comment: @L0Lock i dont understand it so just add me on discord, mine is zealyplayz. also it didn't work

Comment: I will not do that. The whole point of using a forum is precisely to not solve issues behind closed doors so that everyone can see and use the solutions. You need to communicate more; what isn't working? What have you tried?